# Parse 'Cannot do a comparison query for type: (null)' Pointer Comparison

Tags: ios, objective-c, pointers, parse-platform

I have 3 classes in Parse.  I have a **Tip** Class, a **Comment** Class, and a **User** Class.

On my initial View Controller I want to show the number of comments for the displayed "Tip".

As you can see below, Inside my **Comment** class I have a pointer called **tip** that points to which **Tip** the comment belongs to.

I have set up a method to handle my query to get the total number of comments and then display the text within a UIButton called **commentsButton**.

However, whenever I execute this method in my **viewDidLoad** I get a ***'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'Cannot do a comparison query for type: (null)'***

Here is my method:

```
- (void) getCommentNumber
{
    __weak typeof (self) weakSelf = self;
    [ProgressHUD show:@"Loading Number of Comments"];

    PFQuery *commentQuery = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:@"comment"];
    [commentQuery whereKey:@"tip" equalTo:self.tipObject];
    [commentQuery findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock:^(NSArray *objects, NSError *error)
     {
         if (!error)
         {
            weakSelf.dataArray = objects;
            [commentsButton setTitle:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%lu comments",(unsigned long)[objects count]]forState:UIControlStateNormal];
         }
         else
         {
             [ProgressHUD showError:@"Sorry! Unable to load how many comments there are."];
             // Log details of the failure
             NSLog(@"Error: %@ %@", error, [error userInfo]);
         }
     }];
}
```

[image]

Comment: `self.tipObject` is probably `nil`.

Comment: is it possible to do a class to class comparison?  Like:

    `PFQuery *tipObject = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:@"Tip"];
    PFQuery *commentQuery = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:@"comment"];
    [commentQuery whereKey:@"tip" equalTo:tipObject];`

Comment: Problem with this line    [commentQuery whereKey:@"tip" equalTo:self.tipObject]; Just check self.tipObject is valid object or nil...thats it!